# Boundaries in diagram with Date as X

Tags: web-part, date-time

I've recently been trying to build a line diagramm webpart with dates as X
Problem is: I can't find a way to adjust the boundaries of the diagram which causes it to start in ~1900

At the moment it looks like this: http://i.imagebanana.com/img/4eg62aqv/dateAsX.PNG

Anyone who can help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Specify a minimum for the X axis as outlined here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-nz/sharepoint-server-help/create-a-chart-by-using-the-chart-web-part-HA101889211.aspx

Edit the page with the chart web part, click Data & Appearance > Customize your Chart > Step 3: Chart Element Properties (on the left) > Axes and Grid Lines.

Enter the minimum X axis value as a number, for example 1-Jan-2000 will be 36526, just like in the Excel Date system.